# To-be-injected dependency is null

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I am trying to inject an attribute of an Activity, but it just gets set to null, and I can't find out why.

```
@Inject
AuthenticationViewDispatcher mAuthenticationViewDispatcher;

--------

public class AuthenticationViewDispatcher {

    @Inject
    public AuthenticationViewDispatcher() {
    }

}

----

@Singleton
@Component(modules = ApplicationModule.class)
public interface ApplicationComponent extends AbstractComponent {

    Context context();
}

----

@Module
public class ApplicationModule {

private final Application mApplication;

public ApplicationModule(final @NonNull Application application) {
    this.mApplication = application;
}

@Provides
@Singleton
Context provideApplicationContext() {
    return this.mApplication;
}

----

@Singleton
@Component(modules = DataModule.class)
public interface DataComponent {
}

----

@PerActivity
@Component(dependencies = {ApplicationComponent.class}, modules = {LoginModule.class})
public interface LoginComponent extends ApplicationComponent {

    void inject(final InjectedActivity baseActivity);
}

----
@Module
public class LoginModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    AuthenticationFlowDispatcher provideAuthenticationViewDispatcher(final @NonNull AuthenticationFlowDispatcher authenticationViewDispatcher) {
        return authenticationViewDispatcher;
    }
}
```

It's not the first time I use this kind of setup, but I've never had this issue before. What am I forgetting?

Comment: That `void inject(That that) ` only works for concrete classes, and in base class you only inject what's visible in the base class.

Comment: I always forget Dagger doesn't work with inheritance the way I'd like it too. Thanks again. Feel free to move your comment to an answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're forgetting that `void inject(That that)` only works for concrete classes, and in base class you only inject what's visible in the base class.

If you want to inject concrete classes, you can for example specify an abstract method in the base

`protected abstract void injectSelf();`

That way the concrete child will be able to call the component's `inject` method upon itself.